# Kivy TextInput not rendering some characters in the font

Tags: python, python-3.x, fonts, kivy

Recently Google announced their Noto font family that claimed to include all Unicode characters. I immediately got interested about emojis, so I grabbed the [NotoEmoji-Regular](https://www.google.com/get/noto/#emoji-zsye) font and threw it in a `TextInput`. However, before that, I checked it inside High-Logic FontCreator to ensure it contained the required characters, which it did. But to my surprise and disappointment, the "" (`0x1F601`) character was rendered as a box. What's the reason that the character wasn't displayed?

The code is as simple as this:

```
from kivy.base import runTouchApp
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput

runTouchApp(TextInput(text = '',
                      font_name = 'NotoEmoji-Regular.ttf'))
```

I am using Linux, Python 3.5, Kivy 1.9.2-dev0. The text provider is sdl2

Comment: Does some other font which has (b&w)emoji in it work or is it the blank box too? Something like this: ☺

Comment: @KeyWeeUsr, I tried with OpenSans-Emoji, same issue. That's weird

Comment: @KeyWeeUsr, actually, never mind. Before, I've tried it with `0x1F601`, which is a part of the "Emoji" category in Unicode, and it didn't work with both fonts. But when I took your symbol (`0x263A`), both of them displayed it. But it isn't in the "Emoji" category, so technically, it's not one of them

Comment: Sorry it wasn't supposed to be exactly that symbol, just an emoji that is displayed in this way e.g. through browser or other phone. Not color-picture, but the flatten and simplified version.

Comment: @KeyWeeUsr, if I understand you correctly, the emoji symbols that are displayed here on this page are not displayed in the `TextInput`. Colorless and flat, just regular emojis

Comment: I'm sure I was able to paste emoji into TextInput with a font that supported it. I think it was some font from android. I was saying that maybe it supports only simple emojis - sorry, don't remember if that emoji was flat or some fancy svg.

Comment: ref [comment](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/issues/4741#issuecomment-261727139)

Comment: @Leva7 normal text also gives me boxes for this font i.e. try text="ABCD", you'll get the same result

Comment: @udiboy1209 that's normal. This font doesn't have Basic Latin except for the numbers, so it shouldn't display letters

Comment: @Leva7 then you should check whether it has the characters you are trying to test. This just shows Kivy doesn't have font fallback to some standard font when characters are missing.